# What is the shortcut to format code in Qt Creator?

Tags: qt, qt-creator, keyboard-shortcuts

I want to format my Qt code via a shortcut in *Qt Creator*, just like `ctrl + shift + F` in *Eclipse*.

But didn't found one in Qt creator options, nor after searching via google.

So, do there has such a shortcut in Qt Creator? If no, then how to format code?

Comment: If by format code you mean indentation, ctrl+(shift+)I is your friend. There is a code beautifier plugin that might do a whole lot more, but I haven't used it myself so I have no shortcut to give you.

Comment: I use clang-format and I [set up an external tool in QtCreator](http://www.pasteall.org/pic/show.php?id=103857)

Comment: @rubenvb The `Beautifier` plugin do works, it need the additional format tool, I just installed `artistic`, and it works, also could define shortcut for it.

Comment: @doug65536 I just tried `artistic`, it's small & simple, I am going to try `clang`, seems the download is big, hope it's more powerful.

Answer (score 35):

You can at least *indent* your code in the following way. First, select the portion of code you want to indent (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>, if you want to indent all source code in the current file) and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd>.

If you're on a Mac OS X, use <kbd>Command</kbd> instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>.

Comment: In addition, rewraping comments is done with `Ctrl+A,E`, similar to vim's `gqap`.

Answer (score 31):

1. First, install clang-format.

   If you're on Ubuntu, you can do it with `sudo apt-get install clang-format`.
2. Then go to `Help -> About plugins`, and check `Beautifier`.
3. Then restart Qt creator.
4. Now, go to `Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard` and find where it says "*Format Current File*" in the middle column, then click on it.

   And at the bottom of this window click on `record`, and record the key sequence that you would like to use to format the current file.

Comment: I don't see Beautifier Plugin

Comment: Using Ubuntu 18.04 I can see a "Beautifier (experimental) in the C++ section of the "About Plugins" dialog. There is also a "ClangCodeModel" plugin... (sounds like providing a similar functionality but I did not test it so far)

Comment: After adding the plug-in I needed to set the `clang-format` path in `Tools -> Options -> Beautifier -> Clang Format`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ClangFormat plugin in combination with the `Ctrl` + `i`

1. Enable the plugin: go to Help > About Plugins, click on ClangFormat
2. Restart Qt Creator
3. Enable formatting with `Ctrl` + `i`
   Tools > Options > C++ > Code Style > 'Format instead of indenting'.
4. Select code and format with `Ctrl` + `I`

https://www.qt.io/blog/2019/04/17/clangformat-plugin-qt-creator-4-9